# How to group same element entry and replace it by an average value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

a dataframe is given with city and the supplies, it can contain other columns (which may have different values). Output city name with maximum supplies, in case of multiple entries for any city output city name with the highest average supplies

example:

dataframe

city supplies   address    columnx        columny

A       3000       xyz         xyz           xyz

B       4000       xyz         xyz           xyz

C       1000       xyz         xyz           xyz

A       4000       xyz         xyz           xyz

D       3000       xyz         xyz           xyz

B       1000       xyz         xyz           xyz

then output should be:

city A supplies 3500

use dataframe functions to groupby city and supplies and output city with most average supply.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution without using pandas ("use python inbuilt libraries")? Or are you allowed to use pandas ("a dataframe is given")? A dataframe in python usually means a pandas dataframe or a dask dataframe. Have you tried anything yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `pandas`, this would calculate average supplies by city:

```
dataframe.groupby('city').supplies.mean()
```

If you want to extract the city with the largest average values for supplies you can do:

```
dataframe.groupby('city').supplies.mean().idxmax()
```

Comment: It is no need to sort, you can use idxmax() instead.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good tip! I've changed the code to  reflect your suggestion